# Building an XML

Tags: xml, standards

Which is the standarized way of writing an XML?
is it

```
<MODEL_NUMBER></MODEL_NUMBER>
```

or

```
<MODELNUMBER></MODELNUMBER>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is:

(a) there is no standard

(b) there is not even any widespread agreement on conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Most style guidelines I have read (e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp) recommend using underscores between the two words in an element tag if it improves readability. So casing aside, the most readable would be:

```
 <model_number></model_number>
```

Answer (score 0):

This similar question shows a few options.  I personally prefer ProperCase and camelCase, mostly because I don't like typing underscores, due to my less than perfect typing skills.  That's really more personal bias, and experience working with .NET, where ProperCase and camelCase are more prevalent.

[Case conventions on element names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074447/case-conventions-on-element-names)

Answer (score -1):

Neither of these. By default, element names mustn't be in capital letters.

Maybe `<model.number></model.number>` would be a solution.

Comment: I don't think capital letters are strictly prohibited, FYI.