# Is the at-sign (@) a valid HTML/XML tag character?

Tags: html, xml, tags, character, specifications

I'm doing some HTML stripping using regular expressions (yes, I know, never *parse* HTML with regexes, but I'm just *stripping* it, and I also unfortunately cannot use any external libraries).  I'm using a regex from the Regular Expressions Cookbook, and it has worked great, except I just ran into this problem:

In the string `Bob Saget <bobs@aol.com>`, my regex is matching the email as a tag.

So my question is, is the `@` sign a valid XML or HTML **tag** character?  (I'm not asking whether or not it is valid within an attribute; I know that it is)  If it is not, I will be able to successfully exclude it in my regex.

I'm not sure where to look this up.  I looked [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-NameChar) and I think that says that in XML, the at-sign is not allowed in a tag; however, I would appreciate some concrete proof.

Comment: The problem is rather your naked angled brackets, which should be given by entity or character references. The '@' is a perfectly valid character in any flavour of HTML.

Comment: @Kerrek Of course the `@` sign is a valid character.  But is it valid in a tag?  If I were to give a HTML or XML parser a tag with at signs in it, would it parse it?

Comment: By "valid tag" do you mean "valid element type name"? The answer is "no", [see here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar) for a list of valid characters. The element type name must be a `Name`. Quote: "The ASCII symbols and punctuation marks, along with a fairly large group of Unicode symbol characters, are excluded from names [...]"  ... ah, you already found that.

Comment: @NickAldwin - the `NameChar` specification is a formal grammar. Anything that's not explicitly included is excluded. Your edit should be moved to an answer.

Comment: firefox seems to support it, but only a few people create custom elements and I don't think they would ever use @ in the tagname. Don't strip them, and encode the <, >, &

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After another look at the [XML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/):

A tag consists of:

```
'<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '>'
```

A Name consists of:

```
NameStartChar (NameChar)*
```

A NameStartChar consists of:

```
":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
```

A NameChar consists of:

```
NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
```

The `@` sign is `U+0040`

So the `@` sign is not valid in a NameChar or a NameStartChar, and thus not valid in a Name.

Comment: It's not clear whether this is applicable to HTML, which your original question was focused on.

Comment: The WhatWG HTML specification only allows `[a-zA-Z]` as valid `NameStartChar`. For `NameChar`, it allows `[^\s\0>/]`.