# How to write XPath expression with @attribute

Tags: html, xml, xpath

How to write XPath expression for `@input`. I'm trying this
expression:

```
//input[@input='onSearchInput'].
```

This expression not found.

HTML input tag:

```
<input type="text" class="input" @input="onSearchInput" placeholder="Word search" style="">
```

Comment: that is not valid xml.  should be /> to end element.  When I did that, then your xpath works

Comment: no it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is not well-formed due to the `@` character in `@input`.  Remove the `@` character if you want to use XML-based tools such as XPath.

See also [Is the at-sign (@) a valid HTML/XML tag character?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7065693/290085)

Comment: is it possible the others? e.g. cssSelector

Comment: @Sansli: The markup-up itself is bad, so I wouldn't suggest relying on CSS selectors either, even if you did find an implementation with which it happened to work.