# How to unmarshal XML attributes with colons?

Tags: xml-parsing, go, xml-attribute

Some SVG/XML files I'm working with have dashes and colons in attribute names - for example:

```
<g>
  <a xlink:href="http://example.com" data-bind="121">...</a>
</g>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to unmarshal these attributes using [`golang`](http://golang.org)'s [`encoding/xml`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml) package. While the dashed attributes works, the ones with the colon doesn't:

### [[See here for a live example](http://play.golang.org/p/tuDunv39S9)]

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

var data = `
<g>
    <a xlink:href="http://example.com" data-bind="121">lala</a>
</g>
`

type Anchor struct {
    DataBind  int    `xml:"data-bind,attr"`  // this works
    XlinkHref string `xml:"xlink:href,attr"` // this fails
}

type Group struct {
    A Anchor `xml:"a"`
}

func main() {
    group := Group{}
    _ = xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &group)

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", group.A)
}
```

These are [seemingly legal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1478623/187907) attribute names; any idea how to extract the `xlink:href` one? thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your example fragment is not quite correct, since it does not include an [XML namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) binding for the `xlink:` prefix.  What you probably want is:

```
<g xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <a xlink:href="http://example.com" data-bind="121">lala</a>
</g>
```

You can unmarshal this attribute using the namespace URL:

```
XlinkHref string `xml:"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink href,attr"`
```

[Here](http://play.golang.org/p/l8zf0uL0D7) is an updated copy of your example program with the namespace fix.

Comment: Just to add, I had trouble getting attributes prefixed with "xml", like `xml:lang="eng"`, but seems like since xml is default(?) you can just use `\`xml:"lang,attr"\``  as usual.

Comment: Well, the `xml:` prefix for attributes doesn't actually identify an XML namespace.  It was defined before the XML Namespace spec.

Comment: An example for what localhost is referring to above, that failing line would change to ``xml:"href,attr"`` .. like so https://play.golang.org/p/30p2ebQMD0