# golang xml Unmarshal

Tags: xml, go

I am following the below example and trying to parse the xml and get day, date, high ,text, code.
https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#examples

parsing Not working:

```
<yahooWeather>
<yweather:forecast day="Fri" date="18 Dec 2009" low="49" high="62" text="Partly Cloudy" code="30"/>
</yahooWeather>
```

parsing Working fine:

```
<yahooWeather>
<yweather day="Fri" date="18 Dec 2009" low="49" high="62" text="Partly Cloudy" code="30"/>
</yahooWeather>
```

trying to read/understand xml stadards and golang xml package. In mean time please suggest me the solution
or doc

My code:
http://play.golang.org/p/4scMiXk6Dp

Comment: the key concept you're missing is "XML Namespaces"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is addressing the correct XML namespace, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934327/golang-how-to-unmarshal-xml-attributes-with-colons). In your original code, you had declared the `YahooWeather` struct like this:

```
type YahooWeather struct{

    Name yw `xml:"yweather"`

}
```

This doesn't work as expected because `yweather` is the namespace of `yweather:forecast`, not the actual element. In order to capture the `forecast` element, we need to include the namespace definition in the XML string.

```
var data1 = []byte(`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
    <yweather:forecast day="Fri" date="18 Dec 2009" low="49" high="62" text="Partly Cloudy" code="30"/>
</rss>
`)
```

Presumably this is ok because you're really going to be pulling this RSS file from the server, and the namespace definitions will be there in the real data. You can then define `YahooWeather` like this:

```
type YahooWeather struct{

    Name yw `xml:"http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0 forecast"`

}
```

You can play with [my fork of your playground](http://play.golang.org/p/GHPIbPJtbI) if you'd like.

Comment: note that the second Unmarshal in your example is silently failing, and printing the same struct that was used in the first Unmarshal.

Comment: @JimB Yup. I suspected that might be happening, so I made a new variable `c` and tried unmarshaling the `yweather` version. It failed, as expected.

Comment: I can only say that I had no idea you could add namespace definitions to the `xml` decoration field like that! That's simply amazing!