# How to give the "Root Element" name in two Words In XML

Tags: xml

I want to give the root element name as two words, how to give it..

for Example,

```
<parent>
  <child1>content</child1>
  <child2>content</child2>
</parent>
```

Root Element "Parent" has to be given as "Parent Name"
I Want to use SPACE in the Root Element

Comment: You can't. XML identifiers cannot have spaces in them.

Comment: Instead use a "-", like `parent-name`.

Comment: these r basics.first read naming conventions

Comment: what do you mean "not working"?? It's valid XML, so that's not the problem. If you're talking about things "not working", it starts to sound like you have a deeper problem than simply XML naming conventions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML Elements cannot have spaces in their names. That's the rule.

If you are converting to/from a data source with spaces in the field names, then you'll need to change those spaces into something else during the conversion process.

I suggest using underscores, as this is a valid character in XML element names - eg `<parent_name>`

You can also use hyphens if you prefer. Dots, colons and some other punctuation characters are also okay, but can get complicated (eg because colons are also used for name-spacing), so best to avoid them and stick with hyphens and underscores.

The other common way of representing multiple words in an element name is to use camel case, which is where your element name has capital letters to represent the start of each word - eg `<ParentName>`.

You might want to read this question here on SO for more discussion on this: [Is there a standard naming convention for XML elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442529/is-there-a-standard-naming-convention-for-xml-elements)

Hope that helps.